# Combo box for all control

Tags: javascript, combobox, filter, textbox, listbox

I created a filterable drop Down List using JavaScript. This is the List Box Coding.

```
<select name="d1" class="leftselect" id="d1" size="5"  ondblclick="DropDownTextToBox('d1','t1');" style="display:none;" >
                <option>axcsus-COMMON STOCK</option>
                <option>aces</option>
            <option>bdfs</option>
            <option>befs</option>
                <option>behs</option>
            <option>dfgh</option>
                <option>dhes</option>
                <option>dwww</option>
            <option>pass</option>
                <option>pass</option>

</select>
```

I created 4 Text Field and a arrow character. If i click the arrow character , I'll show the list at the bottom of the control.

```
<div id="div_name" style="float:left;z-index: 20;">
   <input name="t1"  type="text"  id="t1" onkeyup="value_filtering('d1','t1');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d1','t1')" />
   <input type="button" class="rightselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t1');"  value="&#9660;" />        
</div>

<div class="inputbox">
   <input name="t2" class="inputbox" type="text"  id="t2"  onkeyup="value_filtering('d2','t2');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d2','t2')" />
   <input type="button" class="leftselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t2');"  value="&#9660;" />
</div>

<div style="float:left;text-align:center;" >
    <input name="t3" type="text"  id="t3" onkeyup="value_filtering('d3','t3');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d3','t3')" />
    <input type="button" class="rightselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t3');"  value="&#9660;" />
</div>

<div class="inputbox">
    <input name="t4" class="inputbox" type="text"  id="t4"  onkeyup="value_filtering('d4','t4');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d4','t4')" />
    <input type="button" class="leftselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t4');" value="&#9660;" />
</div>
```

In the display List function I'm getting the corresponded textbox position and displayed the List Control under the Text Box. Okie. Now my problem is If i select any option in the text box, I need to display the selected value to the textbox which the listbox shown under. After selecting the value from the list box, How i find in which text box showing the List ? Dynamically how can i find the text box id ?

This is my JS code for displaying the Listbox to the corresponding TextBox.

```
function displayList(ele,txt)
    {
        vis=document.getElementById(ele);
        obj=document.getElementById(txt);
        if (vis.style.display==="none")
                vis.style.display="block";
        else
            vis.style.display="none";

                vis.style.position = "absolute";

            //alert(getElementPosition(txt).top + ' ' + getElementPosition(txt).left);

    vis.style.top = getElementPosition(txt).top+obj.offsetHeight;
    vis.style.left = getElementPosition(txt).left;
    }
```

Note : I can call this function at the click event of arrow button. I can easily pass the text Field Id. But in the case ListBox action i can't send the particular ID of the Text Field.

Comment: @hsalama : i edited the above question. Please have a look on the post.

Comment: Are you opposed to using libraries like jquery or mootools? This will get very messy before you know it!

Comment: @hsalama : With Jquery shall i do this job ? Any tutorial available ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no opposition to using [jquery](http://jquery.com) you can using the jquery UI built-in [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)  which will do pretty much what you're looking for.  For more advanced and nicer plugins you can try [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
var targetInput=null;
function displayList(ele,txt) {
    vis=document.getElementById(ele);
    obj=document.getElementById(txt);
    targetInput = obj;
    if (vis.style.display==="none") {
        vis.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        vis.style.display = "none";
        vis.style.position = "absolute";
        //alert(getElementPosition(txt).top + ' ' + getElementPosition(txt).left);
        vis.style.top = getElementPosition(txt).top+obj.offsetHeight;
        vis.style.left = getElementPosition(txt).left;
    }
}
function selectList(txt) {
    if (!targetInput) return;
    targetInput.value = txt.value;
    txt.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<div id="div_name" style="float:left;z-index: 20;">
   <input name="t1"  type="text"  id="t1" onkeyup="value_filtering('d1','t1');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d1','t1')" />
   <input type="button" class="rightselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t1');"  value="&#9660;" />        
</div>

<div class="inputbox">
   <input name="t2" class="inputbox" type="text"  id="t2"  onkeyup="value_filtering('d2','t2');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d2','t2')" />
   <input type="button" class="leftselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t2');"  value="&#9660;" />
</div>

<div style="float:left;text-align:center;" >
    <input name="t3" type="text"  id="t3" onkeyup="value_filtering('d3','t3');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d3','t3')" />
    <input type="button" class="rightselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t3');"  value="&#9660;" />
</div>

<div class="inputbox">
    <input name="t4" class="inputbox" type="text"  id="t4"  onkeyup="value_filtering('d4','t4');" onkeypress="onEnter(event,'d4','t4')" />
    <input type="button" class="leftselect" onclick="displayList('d1','t4');" value="&#9660;" />
</div>

<select name="d1" class="leftselect" id="d1" size="5" ondblclick="DropDownTextToBox('d1','t1');" onclick="selectList(this)" style="display:none;">
                <option>axcsus-COMMON STOCK</option>
                <option>aces</option>
            <option>bdfs</option>
            <option>befs</option>
                <option>behs</option>
            <option>dfgh</option>
                <option>dhes</option>
                <option>dwww</option>
            <option>pass</option>
                <option>pass</option>

</select>
```